# Accessing Beagle Bone Ram Registry

Tags: c, beagleboneblack

I am quite new to C in general, and I am trying to go for a small RAM check on embedded Linux.

I am working with a Beagle Bone Black revC, and Debian 6.3.0.

For some functions, I want to read and write from/to RAM registry to e.g. check the data bus for functionality.

Theoretically, I understand, what needs to be done.
Open /mem/dev -> map some memory -> write and read to/from physical address

Now, how do I find out, which addresses I can use for such tasks?

Edit:

I used the advice of the comments and mapped some memory using mmap. If I understand correctly 'PROT_WRITE' leaves me with writable memory adresses.
Implementing this, I can read out the contents of that part of memory.

```
map = (int*)(mmap(NULL,MAPPED_SIZE,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,_fdmem,DDR_RAM_PHYS));
```

Now I am still ending up with Segementation Faults, when i try to use those physical addresses.
Reading the man-page of mmap, this leaves me wondering, if I end up with writable addresses or just being able to try to write in general?
E.g. if I map the physical addresses of the Kernel with PROT_WRITE, do I end up with a mapping error, or does the error occur during trying to write to those addresses?

Comment: look for how to check the 'memory map' of a Linux device and you'll be almost there

Comment: You might want to use the function: `mmap()` to give the program access to some RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used the advice and edited my post according to the advices over the weekend.